# Using Out of Order Execution on Nvidia Quadro FX 880

Tags: opencl

I am using an Quadro FX 880 card. In my Image Segmentation code, I have divided the image into 4 parts(ie if there are 4000 pixels, each part is of 1000 pixels). I have 8 kernels in my code... first 4 of which are to be executed in parallel and the next four again in parallel but after the first four kernels get executed. Is this possible if I use same command queue for all 8 kernels and specify a clEnqueueNDRangekernel command for each of the first four kernels and I mention OUT_OF_ORDER argument while creating the command queue...? And if this is possible how to execute the next four kernels in parallel, that are to executed after first four kernels..? Can I give a clWaitForEvents command after the first four kernels and then specify the next four kernels..? will this guarantee that the first four kernels are executed in parallel and the next four are executed after them but in parallel..?

I think clEnqueueTask would make my code slow, since I have about 1000 pixels in each kernel and clEnqueueTask allows gobal_workitem_size and the local_work_item_size to be just 1....!

I am not sure whether all these things can be done...and what is wrong or right... so I just need a confirmation...! But if not in this way please suggest an alternative way...!

Answer (score 1):

Newer devices should support running multiple kernels on multiple command queues in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The FX880M is a compute capability 1.2 device. It doesn't support simultaneous/concurrent kernel execution, only execution-copy overlap. You can create a command queue with out of order execution, but it won't have the effect you are asking about.

Comment: What if I create multiple command queues,i.e. one command queue for each kernel... will they be executed in parallel... on different compute units? The 4 kernels I am toking about contain the same code but I execute them for different set of data, ie if I have 512X512 size image, I create 4 parts of it, of size 256x256 pixels and do the same processing on each part by giving 4 different clEnqueueNDRangeKernel calls, which would be enqueued for different command queues.! Will this make the code parallel or will just increse the overhead of craeting 4 kernels..?

Comment: As I said in my answer, this requires hardware features that your GPU does not have. The requirement is non-negotiable. You can't do this on the device you are asking about.

Comment: @user1770678 Of course, you can always just rewrite your algorithm to branch differently depending on the pixel being processed, since I assume the image is divided into four quarters, the cost of branching will be negligible as all items in any work group will almost always take the same branch. That way you only launch one kernel which does slightly different things depending on the pixel's position.

Comment: Thomas:: is it possible to achieve a speed up by creating multiple command queues for the same data like I am planning to do...? 

@Talonmies, I think multiple command queues are supported by my Gpu... what if anyone has a different code for every kernel and so creates multiple command queues to execute them in parallel...?

Comment: @user1770678: You can have multiple command queues, but they don't result in concurrent kernel execution **because your GPU architecture doesn't support it**. How many times would you like to be told the same thing?

Comment: Oh yeah I understand this, but then how does my device support task parallelism using clEnqueueTask...?

Comment: @ShreedharPawar: As I have now said about *six* times, it doesn't. You can overlap data transfer with kernel execution, but (again) the hardware doesn't support any sort of kernel concurrency or parallelism. You can queue up as many as kernel launches as you like in whatever arrangement you like, but the driver will only ever schedule up and run one kernel at a time, because that is all the hardware is capable of.

Comment: @talonmies I think he is confused about the difference between individual work items and work groups (which enqueueNDRangeKernel does).